# Definition of vector cross product

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, conventions

I hope I'm right in saying that the cross-product, $\vec{A}\times \vec{B}$ of two vectors is defined by a right hand rule (e.g. if $\vec{A}$ points along the forefinger and $\vec{B}$ along the second finger, then $\vec{A} \times\vec{B}$ points along the thumb)  if you're using a right handed co-ordinate system, but by a left hand rule if you're using a left handed coordinate system.

What motivates this difference in rules? I understand the concept of right and left-handed co-ordinate systems, but I don't understand why our definition of the cross-product itself should depend on the co-ordinate system. What would be wrong with continuing to define the cross product using a right hand rule, while using a left-handed co-ordinate system, and accepting the that its components will have different signs in a different co-ordinate system?
[I'm using the cross product as an example of an axial vector.]

One more go at explaining my difficulty (mental block?) Take the magnetic Lorentz force, $\vec{F}=q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$. What has the direction of $\vec{F}$ to do with co-ordinate systems? Isn't it fixed relative to $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$ by a right hand rule (and various other conventions)?

Comment: In a left hand coordinate we have $\hat i\times\hat j=-\hat k$. You won't obtain that by using right hand rule. You'll need the left hand rule.

Comment: Why complicate matters with conflicting hand-rules and coordinate systems, where you have to bother about the signs? It's much easier to keep things simple. Not sure if there's a deeper explanation for this.

Comment: @Koo Zhengqun  It seems to me to complicate things to define a cross product differently according to co-ordinate systems. I've always thought of a vector as independent of co-ordinate system. I expect I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The cross-product is dependent upon the vector field/space in which it is defined.  You cannot apply different rules to one and not the other.

Comment: There is a different relationship between the concepts. The coordinate system and cross product are cloaely related, in that you can describe the cross product in terms of coordinate system, or conversely, coordinate system in terms of cross product. You can use vectors to describe cross products as well, but you can also use vectors to describe lots of other things. On the other hand, you can't really use cross products to describe vectors.

Comment: The right-handed and left-handed are conventional, but truly are according to mathematics formulas.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, everyone. I've added another short paragraph to the initial question to help explain my difficulty, but I expect I'm a hopeless case.

Comment: @Diracology "In a left hand coordinate we have î ×ĵ =−k̂ . You won't obtain that by using right hand rule. You'll need the left hand rule". But I $did$ just obtain it using the right hand rule: rotating the left hand forefinger ($\vec{i})$) into the left hand second finger ($\vec{j})$) a right handed screw advances in the opposite direction to the way the left hand thumb points.

Comment: the direction of $\textbf{F}$ and of $\textbf{v}$ are independent of the coordinate system, these are vectors.  But $\textbf{B}$ is not a *vector* (it is a pseudo-vector) and the product operation $\times $ is defined so that when a vector is combined with a pseudo-vector you get a vector, hence the swimming rules.

Comment: Let me see if I've understood...

Comment: If there are still any patient people out there, let me see if I've understood…  Is it the case that (1) the first comment above  (by Diracology) is wrong, and that even in a left handed system, $\vec{i} \times \vec{j} = \vec{k}$ and that (2) in a left-handed system the magnetic Lorentz force is $\vec{F} =-q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$. If so, I think I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some level your question just boils down to conventions: there are several sets of sign conventions that all give the right answers, so you just need to find one that you find conceptually satisfying and stick with it.

It might be helpful to point out that you can only ever directly measure polar vectors. Axial vectors can be thought of as just mathematical abstractions that only appear as *intermediate* steps in a physical process. For example, you are correct that in the Lorentz force law ${\bf F} = q{\bf v} \times {\bf B}$, the force is a physical quantity whose direction should not change sign under coordinate transformations. But remember that the magnetic field itself is physically determined by the Biot-Savart law (in the magnetostatic approximation; things get more complicated in the dynamic case but the parity transformation properties don't change):
$${\bf B}({\bf x}) = \int d^3x'\ \frac{{\bf J({\bf x}')} \times \hat{\bf r}}{r^2},$$
where ${\bf r} := {\bf x} - {\bf x}'$. Therefore, the magnetic field is an axial vector and can't be directly measured; you can only ever observe its effect by taking *another* cross product to get a force via the Lorentz force law.

The punch line is that you can always expand out any physically measurable vector as being determined by an *even* number of cross products. For example, you can write the magnetic force on a particle as
$${\bf F}({\bf x}) = q{\bf v} \times \int d^3x'\ \frac{{\bf J({\bf x}')} \times \hat{\bf r}}{r^2}.$$

So there are two different but physically equivalent ways to conceptualize a change in the handedness of your coordinate system. You can think of all "right-handed" cross products becoming "left-handed" cross products, in which case all axial vectors (like the magnetic field) will physically switch direction - but since they can't be physically measured, this has no consequences on observable physics. Or you can, as you prefer, think of cross products as being "physically" determined by the right-hand rule, in which case they don't switch direction because they don't care about your choice of coordinates. In this framework, the magnetic field does not switch direction under a coordinate inversion. Both conceptualizations lead to identical observable physics: since any directly observable vector is made up of an even number of cross products, it either picks up no minus signs or an even number of minus signs under a coordinate inversion. In either case, its direction is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Allowing a choice of viewpoints seems the way forward for me. I knew that my difficulties were more about language and conventions than about the Physics or even the maths. But many elementary presentations of this issue are dogmatic and, for me, confusing.

Comment: Hey! Do you have any reference for the fact that "you can always expand out any physically measurable vector as being determined by an even number of cross products." ? Or if I understand correctly, for all the axial/pseudo vectors in physics, their actual physical content is actually an axis/line/direction and a norm, but not an orientation ? so they're vectors with a norm defined "up to orientation"? (but with the orientation degree of freedom removed) basically, as vectors is the closest object we have?

Comment: For scalars, it would be like we're only interested in the absolute value of a number, not its sign

Comment: @Voidt Not quite. The notion of an unoriented vector (but with well-defined magnitude and alignment) that you're describing is sometimes referred to as a "director" (although that word isn't too common). But pseudovectors are not directors; they still have a well-defined orientation. Once you've chosen a *global* sign convention for how to take cross products, the direction of a magnetic field is physically observable.

Comment: @Voidt If the magnetic field were a director, then you could independently choose whether or not to reverse the direction of every magnetic field vector without changing the observable physics. But you can't; once you've established a sign convention for the orientation of one magnetic field vector at one point in space, that uniquely determines the orientation of the magnetic field at every other point in space as well.

Comment: @Voidt Put another way: in the theory of classical EM, the magnetic field has a *global* $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. If the magnetic field were a director, then it would have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ *gauge* symmetry, so the orientation would be physically unobservable. These are very different situations.

Comment: I see, if I understand correctly: it's not *a single* pseudovector that's invariant under sign exchange/, but the *cross product operation itself*? So the cross product operation is algebraically defined *up to the orientation of the vector space we're working with (the basis frame)*.  
But this is just a mathematical artefact: there is no natural physical orientation of the universe. 
So we have to pick one to define our vectors properly.

Comment: And this orientation is what determines the hand rule (right for positively oriented space or left for negatively oriented), and which will *fix* the cross-product operation defined on that space, i.e determine altogether the sign of all the pseudovectors obtained through the cross-product.
So fundamentally, it comes down to a few things:

Comment: - the fact that the cross product is an operation defined in an oriented 3D vector space, and that it's not well defined as long as we didn't fix an orientation (the orientation is hidden in the hand rule, and the RHR is the side most commonly picked, it is now an accepted convention everywhere),

Comment: - So the cross product is well defined only as long as we defined the orientation of our space (arbitrarily, as nature isn't oriented), and once that is done, all of our pseudovectors have a fixed common orientation/sign. But one can wonder, why is that *physically*? What makes it so that quantities defined from cross-products can't be observed and are orientation independant?

Comment: Finally,  I don't remember properly defining the cross product in any of my maths courses. I think introducing properly the arbitrary binary degree of freedom of an *orientation* for vector spaces (which defines *oriented vector spaces*), and then properly defining the cross product as operations *defined only on such oriented vector spaces*, could lift some of the misunderstanding about the RHR/cross product/pseudovectors: it's a rule that only comes down to the choice of orientation of the vector space we're working with.
Sorry for all the replies, I'm trying to make sure I understand!

Comment: Hi, I dug a bit deeper and there's apparently a few ways to understand pseudo vectors better mathematically and physically.

Mathematically: 
 The cross product operation between a and b should actually be defined as *the Hodge dual of the 2-form built from the outer product of a and b". Indeed, a pseudovector is actually paired with an antisymmetric bilinear form (2-form) through the Hodge dual operator. The fact that the pairing of a 3D 2-form can be written in a 3D pseudovector is just luck, as 3D 2-forms have 3 independent components, which doesn't have to be the case in dim $n\neq3$.

Comment: In $\dim V=n$, a general antisymmetric 2-form tensor has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ components. It just happens to be 3 for $n=3$.

Now, the second way to think about pseudovectors is as a representation of Lie algebra of rotations in $3D$, $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, called the *hat map*. Indeed, $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are isomorphic, and the Lie Bracket between two $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ elements is given by the cross product between the two associated pseudovectors under this pseudovector representation.

Comment: In both cases, the action of the skew-symmetric matrix representation $M$ of the 2-form/$\mathfrak{so}(3)$ element on a (polar) vector $v$ is through matrix multiplication $Mv$, and the action of the pseudovector $u = \star M = \hat{M}$ associated with $M$ is through the cross product : $Mv = uv := u \times v$

Comment: Finally, it somehow becomes clear that all the physical quantities which are pseudovectors are somehow generators of rotations. The pseudovector representation gives *the axis of rotation* of the object, while its dual Hodge star/hat star matrix form determines *the plane of rotation*.

Comment: @Voidt Yes, the laws of classical physics are invariant under a redefinition of the cross product itself, but not under the sign exchange of any individual pseudovector. Any quantity that we conventionally think of as either the cross product of two (polar) vectors or the generator of a plane rotation is more fundamentally "really" an antisymmetric 2-form. Indeed, this 2-form transforms naturally under parity inversion. In 3 dimensions, it's conceptually to think of the Hodge dual of that 2-form, which is a pseudovector that's easier to picture.

Comment: @Voidt The 2-form is what's physically measurable. In general dimensions, you need to stick with that (and it has the right number of degrees of freedom). E.g. in arbitrary dimensions, the magnetic field is a two-form, not a pseudo vector (and it can have a different number of components than the electric field). Likewise with the angular velocity or angular momentum. These 2-forms are defined independently of any orientation convention for your space (which another way to see why they're more fundamental).

Comment: @Voidt  You only need to define an arbitrary orientation of space when you take the Hodge dual and convert them to pseudovectors. But if you just stick with the 2-form formulation, then you never need to introduce an orientation at all. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560 for a nice pedagogical discussion of the physical intuition for bivectors/two-forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From what I understand, a 2-form is independent of any orientation indeed. One only needs to define an orientation for things like defining a basis, taking the Hodge dual of a form or integrating a form. 
I'll have a look at that paper!

Comment: Am I right though that in order to really understand where these 2-forms (pseudovectors) come from in physics is because the antisymmetric matrices are representations of the linear algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ (rotations)?

Comment: Finally, I feel like these kind of things at the intersection of maths and physics, and more specifically of how physicists use mathematics in this manner, is not really taught in usual classes. Is there any good reference for these kind of things, how does one get to learn this stuff?

Comment: @Voidt Yes, I would agree that the "fundamental" reason why the infintesimal rotations are represented by two-forms is because those two-forms are really representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ (where $n$ may or may not equal 3). Unfortunately, I don't know of a comprehensive good reference for these things; I mostly use a fairly random mixture of Wikipedia, Googling, and talking to people.